# mongodb geospatial query for multyindex data

Tags: mongodb, spatial, geo

I have a collection of like so :

`db.records.save( {
  name : "John Smith",
  addresses : [ {
                 context : "home" ,
                 loc : [ 55.5, 42.3 ]
                } ,
                {
                 context : "work",
                 loc : [ -74 , 44.74 ]
                }
              ]
} )`

And I've created an index like this:

`db.records.createIndex( { "addresses.loc": "2d" } )`

Now when I try and make a query like:

`db.Company.findOne({ "stores.loc" : { $near :[55.5, 42.3]}})`

What I expect to get is john smite with an array of addresses with **only** the relevant address, what I get is john smite with all of the addresses, So I do not know.

How do I solve this?

Comment: is there any specific reason of having all address of John in a single document ?

Comment: Because all of those locations are within one document, it finds the document near `[55.5, 42.3]` and returns the whole document. Maybe consider "flattening" the schema (i.e. use one document for each address).

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed if you can alter your schema to take one address in a document and get nearest node from there then:

```
db.records.save( {
  name : "John Smith",
  address_context: "home",
  address_loc : [ 55.5, 42.3 ]
} )

db.records.save( {
  name : "John Smith",
  address_context: "work",
  address_loc : [ -74 , 44.74  ]
} )
```

Now create a index on address_loc and query, you will get relevant nearest nodes